# HTACCESS code not working for vanity URLS

Tags: .htaccess, url, vanity-url

Right now, the following URLs are displayed:

`www.mysite.com/account.php?username=$username`

What I want is:

`www.mysite.com/$username`

I'm using the following code in my `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /account.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it doesn't work: URLs are the same as before.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule does only this:

If someone requests `www.mysite.com/$username`, internally server the resource at `/account.php?username=$username`.

That's all. The syntax being `RewriteRule <the URI that matches this> <gets internally rewritten to this>`

So you have nothing that does anything about changing the URL. That's not how mod_rewrite works. What it sounds like you want is to be able to externally redirect the browser so that what's in the location bar changes. To do that, it's a lot more complicated:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /account\.php\?username=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: +1 for the clarity. The URL rewriting works ( i can see it in the address bar) but now, instead of the user's account being displayed, i  see my 404 custom error page. Any idea why?

Comment: @ChHr is there some other CMS or any other rules which may be interferring? You still need to use the rules that you have in your question along with the redirect above.

Comment: Please see my edited question, I include my full htaccess. Could there be something interfering ?